# A Most Excellent Code Golf Adventure

Tags: code-golf, number, game, restricted-source

You dudes, the [Most Excellent Adventure](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Most_Excellent_Adventure) is a home brew roleplaying game system based on the Bill & Ted Films, *plays gnarly air guitar riff*.

In this game system, when you draw from your dice pool (you have between 1 and 12 ten-sided dice, with faces labelled 0-9) you need to connect the results as a phone number on your phone pad:

[image]

Here one person has rolled 4, 2, 8, 3, 8, and 2, dialling 3-2-2-4-8-8. The other 7, 4, 6, 3, 9, and 4, only dialling 4-4-7 or 3-6-9. And the longest number wins.

Bill and Ted want to play this game on their telephone kiosk, but haven't the first clue about programming. As Station isn't around, they want you to program it. The kiosk had access to all programming languages and OSs past and future (causality forbids you using any future technology... No imaginary python 7 !)

Your input is two numbers between 1 and 12, representing the number of dice player 1 and player 2 have respectively. The output is the result for each player, and the length of the largest number they could dial.

Input: `8 10`
Output:

```
Player 1 rolled 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 with longest dialable number of 8.     
Player 2 rolled 8 8 8 2 3 1 4 0 3 3 with longest dialable number of 10.
```

Numbers can be reordered and pressing the same key twice counts as two digits (which is why the above sequence `8 8 8 2 3 1 4 10 3 3` makes a six digit number not a 4 digit number)

Also, as you're programming this in a telephone kiosk you can only access 0-9, a-z, the `*` and a `#` keys in your code. Letters are accessed by repeated typing, much like on a mobile phone. *Every other key must be input in the kiosk as its ASCII code in hex like so: `#0a` **the upshot is when scoring your submission, these keys "cost" three times as many***.<sup>[Unclear / Incorrect?]</sup>

For instance to type `~` you press the hash key once, the `7` and then `3` three times to cycle through the digits `3de`. This gives the code `#7e` which corresponds to `~`. When you upload you code here you can just type the `~`, and count it as five characters.

The keypad looks a little like this: [image: Telephone keypad]

For instance If your code had `print()` that would cost 15 for the `print` (`7p 7pqr 4ghi 6mn 8t`) plus 6 for the `()` (`#28 #29`).

This is code golf as Bill and Ted will get bored otherwise. Let the coding commence *plays gnarly air guitar riff*.

Comment: @m.buettner You're not allowed the star or hash character.

Comment: Never mind, I somehow stopped readong that sentence at "can't dial them".

Comment: You roll a 12-sided dice to obtain a number from 0-9? Is this right?

Comment: I think your tags are not going to work for this challenges. First, the restriction is really arbitrary and doesn't make codes any more interesting. And second it is not a good fit for [tag:popularity-contest]. What should I judge by? Popularity of the language/poster? And your idea with added features make this challenge too broad.

Comment: @nneonneo if I'm not mistaken you roll 12 six sided dice.

Comment: @Anzeo which makes it even more interesting how he can throw these numbers.

Comment: How do you throw a 0? I can take an educated guess, but it should be in the rules explicitly...

Comment: @all I will redo the rules in a minute please bear with me.

Comment: After the years of learning how to write good questions, I've come back in time to rewrite this one so that its more gnarly, and most excellent.

Comment: @Howard I've made some quite drastic edits, how does it look now?

Comment: The restriction to only using `0123456789ab*#` rules out even the esoteric languages most commonly used on this site. You'll be lucky to get one answer, let alone two. PS What d10s are you using which have `10` rather than `0`?

Comment: -1. The challenge of computing the exact probability is tricky by itself, and your character restriction rules out pretty much any useful code, let alone one that does what you want.

Comment: Isn't the maximum length equivalent to `min(#dice, 10)`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I thought the restriction would be fun, I'll see how many answers we get. The dice are these http://www.thediceshoponline.com/images/productimages/1168_1_big.jpg

Comment: If by maximum length you mean for that particular roll, how do you define the probability? Is that the probability of a roll that allows a path at least that long?

Comment: @jandvorak not if you roll all of one number

Comment: Your definition of "unreadable" is too subjective for code golf and it allows too much room for tactical voting.

Comment: @jandvorak yes your assumption is correct. If it is to hard I can lift the restriction.

Comment: Please use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiii?cb=1) next time

Comment: @Jan yeah, I thought the question was ready...

Comment: Just  to clarify: is dialing `3-2-2-4-8-8` equivalent to `3-2-4-8`? If so, is `3-2-3-2-4-8`?

Comment: @Jan that should be clear from the example but I've spelled it out. Is the extra cost of characters clear enough?

Comment: Does your revision #4 mean that `,-./\]^_|}~` and both cases of `lmno` (and most of Unicode) are still inaccessible? The hex codes of their ASCII codes contain `CDEF`.

Comment: @jandvorak why would that make them inaccessible? You can access 0-9 as well as a-b and * and #.  That is `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*#`

Comment: How would you encode `~`? The obvious solution would be `#7f`, but `f` doesn't exist. You can reencode `f` to produce `#7#66`, but the code length doesn't work out. Not to mention your encoding is lossy since an escape sequence escapes to itself.

Comment: @jandvorak the is an f in my list above

Comment: Uh... You can't input letters yet they cost one point each? How so? So, alphanumerics, asterisks and hashes cost one each, and the rest costs three each? How does that match up with your storyline?

Comment: @jandvorak I explain in my post : Also as your programming this in a telephone kiosk you can only access 0-9, a-b, the * and a # keys in your code, every other key must be input in the kiosk as its ASCII code in hex like so #0a the upshot is these keys "cost" three times as many.

Comment: When you say (repeatedly) `a-b`, do you mean `a-z`? There's a difference of 24 characters.

Comment: So... Does `p` cost one, or three points? If one, your comments are incorrect. If three, your example in the body is. Also, if three, how much does `~` cost? Its escape sequence is `#7e`, which you can't type on the phone keypad. Your list in the comment doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: As a side note - what keypad is it that you have in mind? Most of them doesn't have the `a`, `b` keys. Not even the one on your diagram does. The ones that do that I know of also have `c` and `d`.

Comment: Sorry all I made a massive mistake with "a-b" vs "a-z"

Comment: @jandvorak better?

Comment: I think it's clear now. It's still primarily a rather difficult mathematical challenge with unusual code scoring mechanics.

Comment: @jandvorak thanks glad it's clear

Comment: The roll "8 8 8 2 3 1 4 0 3 3" can be reordered "3 3 3 2 1 4 8 8 8 0" to make a 10 digit number on the keypad, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @algorithmshark well spotted

Comment: What is left to collapse?

Comment: Did you try this question in the sandbox first?

Comment: @nneonneo no. But I've learnt my lesson.

Comment: Here's a Perl program that converts a program to a sequence of digits, as well as outputting the total score. Although this code isn't reversible because it's not self-synchronizing (You can't tell whether "222222222" is "abc" or "bbb" or "aa2a" or any of a bunch of choices) I decided that since `#` is an escape to introduce hex sequences, "#" itself has to be coded as `#23`. If that's in error, you can change `my %map = qw(* *);` to `my %map = qw(* * # #);` to allow "#"s to pass through unscathed. Code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NcwRxP9w

Answer (score 3):

## VBScript - 1668 telephone keypresses (was 1708)

My entry is golfed a bit more - I realized (doh!) that the variable names should be characters that require less telephone keypresses (a,d,g,j,etc).

This program produces the output exactly as shown and takes the input as command line parameters.  If line endings are 1 byte there is no advantage to using `:` to put it all on one line (#0a vs #3a).  Run it with `cscript script.vbs 8 10` replacing 8 and 10 with whatever values you want - it tries every combination in order to get the maximum string so it is SLOW.

I just have one question: if you needed a two numbers beside each other that were both on the same key isn't it a bit ambiguous.  Wouldn't the text a=e (22#333333) be the same keypresses as a>d (22#333333)?  How do you differentiate where the character boundaries are?  I didn't specifically check for every possible occurance of where things on the same key are beside themselves and I don't know what I would have done if I did notice it...

```vb
sub b(d,m)
p=true
a=len(m)
for g=1to a-1
p=p and instr(split("7890*1245*123456*2356*124578*123456789*235689*45780*4567890*56890","*")(mid(m,g,1)),mid(m,g+1,1))>0
next
if p and t<a then t=a
if d=""then exit sub
a=len(d)
for g=1to a
w=""
if g>1then w=left(d,g-1)
p=""
if g<a then p=mid(d,g+1)
b w+p,m+mid(d,g,1)
next
end sub
randomize
set m=wscript.arguments
for e=1to 2
d=""
j="Player "+cstr(e)+" rolled"
for t=1to mid(10000+m.item(0)*100+m.item(1),e*2,2)
w=cstr(int(rnd()*10))
j=j+" "+w
d=d+w
next
j=j+" with longest dialable number of"
t=0
b d,""
wscript.echo j+" "+cstr(t)
next
```

Ok, I am finally ready to score my entry - that of course means no more changes to it because of how long it takes to transform it to a score.  The transformed phone input is:

```
77777888222#20222#2833#2222266#29#02277#333887777888333#02222#3335555333666#2866#29#02233336666777
7#2044#3331886666#2022#2331#02277#33377#202266633#20444466677777887777#2877777775555444488#28#2278
90*1245*123456*2356*124578*123456789*235689*45780*4567890*56890#22#22222#22*#22#29#2866444433#2866
#2222244#222221#29#29#2222266444433#2866#2222244#22221#222221#29#29#33330#02266633399988#022444433
33#2077#202266633#2088#3222222#2088444333666#2088#33322#02244443333#2033#333#22#2288444333666#2033
3999444488#2077777888222#02222#3335555333666#2833#29#022333366667777#2044#3331886666#2022#02299#33
3#22#22#02244443333#2044#3333188444333666#2099#3335555333333388#2833#2222244#2331#29#02277#333#22#
22#02244443333#2044#3222222#2088444333666#2077#33366444433#2833#2222244#22221#29#022222#2099#22227
7#2222266#222266444433#2833#2222244#222221#29#02266633399988#02233366633#2077777888222#02277772266
633666666444499999333#0227777733388#2066#33399777772222777744447788#233322777744888663336668877777
#022333366667777#20333#3331886666#202#02233#333#22#22#02255#333#22#5055552299993337777#20#22#22222
22277777887777#28333#29#2222#22#20777766665555555533333#22#022333366667777#2088#3331886666#2066444
433#2810000#222266#233344448833366#280#29*100#222266#233344448833366#281#29#22222333*2#222222#29#0
2299#333222277777887777#28444466688#28777766633#28#29*10#29#29#02255#33355#2222#22#20#22#222299#02
233#33333#222299#02266633399988#02255#33355#2222#22#2099444488444#2055556666666443337777788#203344
44225555222225555333#20666888662223337777#2066663333#22#02288#3330#022222#2033#22222#22#22#0229977
7772222777744447788#233333322224446666#2055#2222#22#20#22#2222222277777887777#2888#29#022666333999
88
```

Comment: You don't need to count newlines as 2 bytes. It does not matter whether you are on Windows or not, here you can always count them as 1 byte.

Comment: I have just had an idea how to make it much shorter - I'll have a new version soon (and I will put the linefeeds back if they count as the same length as a colon)